# Angular 5 form submitted flag undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am new at Angular forms and I am not finding where is the problem.
I get undefined when I try to access submitted flag of the Form. Also when I do console log of the form there is no submitted field.
Here is the code

```
 export class Component implements OnInit {  
  
  formCodicePromozionale: FormGroup;
  formModel: any = {};

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public globalService: GlobalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  } 

  createForm(): void {
    this.formCodicePromozionale = this.fb.group({
      codice: ["", Validators.required],
      tipo: ["", Validators.required],
      statoContatto: ["", Validators.required],
      campagna: "",
      status: ["", Validators.required],
      dataInvio: "",
      note: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  isValidField(field: string, validator?: string) {
    const validatorToBeChecked = validator ? validator : "required";
    if (this.formCodicePromozionale["submitted"]) {
      return !this.formCodicePromozionale.hasError(validatorToBeChecked, [field]);
    }
    return true;
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if(this.formCodicePromozionale.valid){
      console.log("form is valid");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML with only one input

```
    <form
id="dettaglio-codice-promozionale"
#formCodiceProm="ngForm"
novalidate
[formGroup]="formCodicePromozionale"
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
autocomplete="off"
>
<div
  class="row bordered-content"
  style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px"
>
  <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
    <label for="codice">Codice *</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="codice"
      name="codice"
      [(ngModel)]="formModel.codice"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': !isValidField('codice') }"
    />
    <small class="red" *ngIf="!isValidField('codice')">Campo obbligatorio</small>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

see the console log of the Form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access "submitted" field as there is none on the FormGroup. Instead you can access using the following code

```
this.formCodicePromozionale.get('submitted').value
```

When you try to console output you are not able to since there are other fields in the form with Validators set to required. You need to have values for those form controls to bypass the "this.formCodicePromozionale.valid"  check.

```
onSubmit(): void {
   if(this.formCodicePromozionale.valid){
     console.log("form is valid");
   }
}
```